# Can a HDFS Block of 128 MB store two different ORC files of size 1MB each?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, orc

I'm working on storage aspect of Hadoop and exploring on know how ORC files get stored on HDFS block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HDFS, a file is composed of blocks. One block cannot hold multiple files.

Two ORC files, each with 1MB, will need a block per file.

If you are concerned about the actual disk storage it might consume, it will be 2MB only. Though the blocks are 128MB, the disk storage it determined by the size of the actual file/block.

Comment: Thank You @franklinsijo. Also what happens if a single ORC file has two part-m files inside it, will they still be hold on a single block or occupy two different blocks.

Comment: You mean one orc file containing the content of two part-m files? Then it is just one file. The number of blocks depend on the size of the resulting file and orc block size. If the orc file is 200mb in size and the block size is 128mb, then two blocks.

Comment: That clarifies my doubt. Thank you very much @franklinsijo